# git: master repository and bare repositories per developer

Tags: git

We are going to use Git as our source repository. Our plan is to have a master bare repository where we will have the deliverable source code. Changes to this bare repository will be made only by a specific person, who will be in charge of integration.

Each developer will have his own repository in local, where they can do as they want. But since we can guarantee the backups in the developer's pc or laptop, I want to setup a remote repository for each user in the development server, so the developer can push the changes in his local repo to his remote repo. That way all repos(master and developer's) in the dev server will be backup daily.

But I don't have a clear image of how the integration between the user's remote repo and the master one should work. I assume I will need to have a integration repository that will be able to pull from the developer's remote repo and push the integrated changes to the master repo. Also, all repos in the development servers should be bare repositories. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Why don't you use the same repository and let each developer (or perhaps multiple developers) work on a separate branch?  The integrator can then merge into the master branch with normal git tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is more common to delineate with branches rather than repositories, what you describe is a valid flow. So I have to **strongly object** to

> ... you can do that but thats not the idea and the concept of Git.

expressed in @Stony's answer. In fact, it is very much so the idea of git to decentralise the work across many different repositories. Github is a case in point - one forks a repo to have his own instance, does the necessary work in the relevant branches, and after a pull request is sent, the work is pulled into the original repo by the original repo owner. As you describe in your proposed design, changes to this (bare) authoritative repository will be made only by the integrator.

Notwithstanding, you have to consider whether you want to follow the model above or the shared repository model (aka centralised but decentralised), where everyone pushes into the same repository, working on separate branches, maintaining a single authoritative branch that reflects the state of the art, along with release branches. With the shared repository model it is common to follow some variant of the [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) branching model, although of course your mileage could vary. The shared repository model is popular for smaller teams sharing one project.

> I want to setup a remote repository for each user in the development server, so the developer can push the changes in his local repo to his remote repo. That way all repos ... will be backup daily.

This is very common approach and you should have no issues here. The developers can have a repository or repositories on the development server that they will clone locally, work and push their branches back to the dev servers, for backup and to publish their work to the integrator. If you have sensitive code or IP this approach is sometimes used to facilitate permission-based control over which repos are accessible by which developers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem ist you can do that but thats not the idea and the concept of Git.

Git is a decentralized version control system so every user has the complete repository on its computer and you don't need a backup for every user.

So there are many ways and concepts to merge branges in your master brange.

Here are some concepts.

https://www.atlassian.com/de/git/workflows